# How to change glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet to glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt while sorting the data in table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change `glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet` to `glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt` when i click on `First Name` for sorting and vice-versa. By the way, my sorting is working fine. Please guide me. How to use this.

my sorting code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder,string currentFilter)
        {
            TestHandle testHandle = new TestHandle();
             ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.FNameSortParam = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "fname_desc" : "";

            var users = from s in testHandle.GetAll()
                        select s;

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "fname_desc":
                    users=users.OrderByDescending(s => s.FName);
                    break;

                default: 
                    users = users.OrderBy(s => s.FName);

                    break;
            }

            return View(users);

        }
```

This is the view:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th >
            @Html.ActionLink("First Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FNameSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></i> 
        </th>

</table>
```

Please guide me.I got stuck here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How and where are you doing the sorting ?How do you know the results are currently sorted by asc/desc ?

Comment: Have you want to use jQuery selector like `$(".glyphicon.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet").attr("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt");`? And how do you know which sorting order currently used for viewing results?

Comment: Is the data inside `ViewBag.FNameSortParam` or ` ViewBag.CurrentFilter` could be used to determine whether you are using an ascending sort or descending sort ? What values you have there ?

Comment: @Shyju, I have edited the the question. Please find the sorting code under index.The sorting is working fine.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto,Please guide me. I have not used JQuery but if it needs then i can use it. But please provide sample code.Thank you.

Comment: I assume default sort order is ascending (without `fname_desc`), thus `sortOrder` is empty by default. Where the user can change the sort order later (I still not seen it)? Is that you want to change CSS class together with table sort order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ViewBag.CurrentSort` stores the current sort order.  You can conditionally render the css class based on the value of that.

`ViewBag.CurrentSort` will have the value "fname_desc" when the result is sorted by descending order and it will have an empty string value otherwise (for ascending order result)

```
<i class="glyphicon @(ViewBag.CurrentSort=="fname_desc"
                  ?"glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt":"glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet")"></i>
```

**Or** 
you can always render the  `glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet` and conditionally append the `-alt` part string  to it to make it `glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt`

```
<i class="glyphicon 
          glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet@(ViewBag.CurrentSort=="fname_desc"?"-alt":"")"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. Thank you once again for your time.